# Is the fifth dimension of Interstellar the same as Block Universe theory?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime-dimensions, wormholes, interstellar-travel

Is the movie [Interstellar (2014)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0816692/) referring to [Block Universe theory](http://www.google.com/search?as_epq=block+universe+theory) of space-time with its concept of a fifth dimension?

Comment: Perhaps this would be more appropriate for [scifi.se]?

Comment: They suggested me to ask here what should I do now? http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/27278/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about guessing what a movie might refer to.

Answer (score 1):

Kip Thorne addresses this in his book [The Science of Instellar](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Science-Interstellar-Kip-Thorne-ebook/dp/B00NUB4EVC). The fifth dimension is a fourth **spatial** dimension i.e. in Interstellar the universe has four dimensions of space and one time dimension.

This is unrelated to the idea of the [block universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time)).

As you'd expect given Kip Thorne's background, there is theoretical support for a fifth dimension, and indeed several extra dimensions, but note that at present there is no **experimental** evidence for any extra dimensions - their existance is purely in the fevered minds of theoreticians. [String theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory) requires nine spatial dimensions to work (plus one time dimension), so if string theory is correct there will be fifth, sixth, seventh, eighth, nineth and tenth dimensions as well as the four we are familar with.

Comment: Also, in certain models of [brane cosmology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) (an extension of string theory which allows for not just 1D strings, but also 2D membranes and other higher-dimensional [branes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane)), there is the possibility that one of the extra spatial dimensions of string theory is "large" rather than curled up at the Planck scale, and that we just aren't aware of it because we're combined to a 3D brane--such a large extra dimension is often referred to as the "bulk", a term also used in the film.